# How to get the available tasks list in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Hi Previously I used the `grunt` in that I want to know the available tasks use `grunt --help`. But same as in `gulp` use `gulp --help` it doesn't show. What is the command to know the available tasks list in gulp

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Yes I got it use the `gulp --tasks` in command then it display the tasks list.

Comment: ahhh i see, that wasn't in 3.9.0 only brought it in with 4.0, nice info

Comment: @MatthewRath `3.9.x` also has the `--tasks` flag. So it works (at least on my local 3.9.1)

Comment: `gulp --tasks-simple` is perhaps nicer because it displays just the top level tasks, a very clean list, whereas `gulp --tasks` also shows the task dependency graph -- I guess it all depends on how much detail you want.

Comment: This limit the task depth to top level and also show descriptions: 

    `gulp -T --depth 1`

Answer (score 54):

```
gulp --tasks-simple
```

This command print a plaintext list of tasks. My local project:

```
~ gulp --tasks-simple
clean
default
```

From [gulp CLI documentation](http://gulpjs.org/CLI.html):

```
~ gulp --version
[03:00:05] CLI version 1.2.1
[03:00:05] Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2
~ gulp --help | grep 'tasks-simple'
  --tasks-simple   Print a plaintext list of tasks for the loaded gulpfile. [boolean]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to use [gulp-help-doc](https://github.com/Mikhus/gulp-help-doc) module, which provides possibility to print usage information based on jsDoc-like comments in a gulpfile. Currently it also supports TypeScript as well. The benefit is that you simply commenting your code without changing gulp API and you have usage info in command-line as well.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this plugin [gulp-task-listing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-task-listing). It gives the `main-tasks` and `sub-tasks list`

Comment: I couldn't get this to work w/ Gulp 3.9. Kept getting this error: 

__**TypeError:** Cannot convert undefined or null to object.__

 because `gulp.tasks` was null.

Comment: yah @VinegarStrokes I have the same issue with Gulp 4.  Did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can write detailed documentation to your tasks in js comments using [gulp-task-doc](https://github.com/megahertz/gulp-task-doc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Gulp 4 you can do the following:

```js
const tasks = gulp.registry().tasks();

// Outputs a JS object: { <task name>: <function>, ...}
console.log(tasks);

const taskNames = Object.Keys(tasks);

// Outputs a JS array: ['<task name>', ...]
console.log(taskNames);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native command that does that but i use [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-help) with the following code:

```
module.exports.help = require('gulp-help')(gulp, {description : false});
```

I can then just run the default `gulp` task in the console and it'll display a list of tasks and definitions.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get in console with out using ` gulp-help`

Comment: Not that i've come across, i imagine there would be a way if you fell back to using nodeJS natively but that sounds overly complex. Post if you find an answer.

Comment: use the `gulp --tasks`

Answer (score 0):

inspired by @matt-gaunt
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65571474/1347601

```js
// gulp task
const list = () => {
    
    const tasks = gulp.registry().tasks();

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(tasks)) {
        console.log(key);
    }

}
gulp.task('list', list);

// gulp process default
gulp.task('list', gulp.series(
    list
));
```